# how do i create a custom UI for a list column

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, custom-list, jquery-ui

What is the best way to create a custom feature to customize the UI of a list by filling in the column and/or field green when the value for row item =   yes/no?

Comment: Since SP2013 with Client Side Rendering.. plenty of blogs around. For SP2010 you need to hack: http://viewmaster365.com/#/How

Comment: You can also check out my step-by-step guides I wrote in my blog about CSR: https://afrait.com/blog/tag/csr/ and the properly best for your scenario will be this: https://afrait.com/blog/traffic-light-column-in-custom-list-en/

Answer (score 0):

I used calculated column to achieve this tons of time. You can check [Here](https://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/apply-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-lists/) or [Here](https://junaidsk.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/color-coding-in-sharepoint-lists-using-calculated-columns/). They are both very quick solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

in June 2017, Microsoft disabled the use of JavaScript in a Calculated Column

That means given answers may not apply  for newer SharePoint versions

For long explanation and work arounds see:
[June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f/218110#218110)

---

**Original answer:**

##no CSR (*and no external script needed like the other answer refers to*)

- Details: https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/#/How and [more examples here on SO](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A32871+ICC)
- Create a new Calculated Column
- **Set the datatype to Number !**
- Paste the Formula
- *change 'TR' to 'TD' if you only want to color the Cell*

  ```
    =[YourYesNoColumn] 
    &"<img src=""/_layouts/images/blank.gif"" onload=""{" 
    &"var row=this;while(row.tagName!='TR'){row=row.parentNode}"
    &"row.style.backgroundColor='" & CHOOSE( [YourYesNoColumn] , "Green" , "Red") & "';"
    &"}"">"
  ```

#### CSR version

*I am too lazy to rewrite the Priority example that uses **no** images*

Rewrite `colorIndex` to match your Yes/No values

```
    function priorityFieldTemplate(ctx) {
    var fieldValue = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name],
        colorIndex=fieldValue.match(/(\d+)/g),//(extract x from '(x) Label'
        color=['none','red','orange','green','brown'][colorIndex],
        circleSize=15,
        H="<svg height={0} width={0}><circle cx={1} cy={1} r={1} fill='{2}'/></svg>";
    return String.format( H , circleSize, circleSize/2, color);
    }
```

ICC iCSR